# Making a private REST API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, backend

I want to make a small API in Rails, so that when it gets a POST request the data sent is stored in database, when it gets a GET request it returns the data...so on. The problem that I'm facing is the `authenticity_token`. When I try to make a POST request I get `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`. I don't want to disable the `authenticity_token` because I would like to use it as a key for being able to use the API. Is it possible to make it static? If not what is the proper way to create a private REST API in Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add at the top of the controller hit by the API call : `skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token`

Comment: That's what I currently have and it obviously works, but I want my API to be private so I need some authorization. I was thinking to use authenticity_token to be a constant string and only the ones who know it to be able to call the API. However I did something like that in controller, but authenticity_token is nicer because it restricts the access in controller in the first place.